# From transform to pose?

Tags: rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm very new to Python and the TF package. Given a transform, I am trying to calculate its pose. How would I do that?

I've seen [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/10323/from-posestamped-message-to-tf-stampedtransform/) and saw the code

```
  tf::Transform grasp_tf(gripperRotation, gripperOrigin);
  tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> grasp_tf_pose(grasp_tf);
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
  tf::poseStampedTFToMsg    (grasp_tf_pose, msg);
```

However, I don't know how I should convert this into Python code. Is there more documentation than the one [given in the wiki](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/tf/html/python/)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190465/from-transform-to-pose?/) by [silentwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/19240/silentwf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You actually linked to the API documentation, which you should definitely read through AFTER going through the tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials.

A transform represents a transformation from frame A to frame B. So could you be more specific about what you mean by 'calculating its pose'. If you mean get the vectors representing the translation and rotation from A to B, there's a few ways (in C++ anyways, python will be somewhat similar):

1&2) First waitForTransform, to make sure the transform is available.

1. lookupTransform, then getOrigin and getRotation on the transform object
2. Initialize a Stamped in frame B with a position vector of (0,0,0), and a quaternion of (0,0,0,1), then transformPose to frame A.

---

tf::poseStampedTFToMsg and similar are helper methods in C++ to convert between the tf and ROS message representation of various objects. A tf representation is used to perform actual mathematical operations, while the ROS message representation is used for communication (publishing/subscribing/broadcasting tf).

A Pose contains a position and an orientation, a Stamped also contains frame and time information needed to transform the pose from one frame to another. Similar pattern applies to vectors, quaternions etc.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silentwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/19240/silentwf/) on 2014-08-20**:
Yes. What I meant was if I had an original Pose information and then a Transform information, how would I use these two information to calculate its resulting Pose?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-21**:
From http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython

transformPose(target_frame, pose_msg) -> pose_msg

**Comment by [gk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27671/gk/) on 2016-08-04**:
However, I dont understand how exactly to calculate the transform which can be used later as in the question. I have two messages coming to me from two different topics. Both of geometry_msgs/poseStamped type. I need to calculate the transform.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf function you're looking for is

```
lookupTransform(target_frame, source_frame, time) -> (position, quaternion)
```

The function returns the translation and rotation of the transformation between the two frames:

```
(translation,rotation) = t.lookupTransform("tf_1", "tf_2", rospy.Time())
```

Now, you have the translation and rotation values, you can construct the [pose msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html).

---

Originally posted by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) with karma: 194 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enriq](https://answers.ros.org/users/29461/enriq/) on 2017-05-31**:
Yes, this is it. I think this is the correct answer. If it is a Pose to a Goal in an autonomous base, just set "Z" to 0, for example